# detailsview does not show all data in one page

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

I am trying to show the sum of totals for different kind of invoices on a web page.
I am using detailsview control, however it does not show all the data in one page. When I enable paging the other types of invoices can be seen on 2nd and 3rd pages.
My SQL command is:

```
SELECT CARI_HESAP_KODU, FATURA_TURU, SUM(KDV_MATRAHI) AS TUTAR FROM LNX_STD_6_016_01_SLSINVOICES WHERE CARI_HESAP_KODU=@mKodu GROUP BY FATURA_TURU, CARI_HESAP_KODU
```

When I run it from SQL I get the proper results:
[image]

But when I run the page and test detailsview I get:
[image]

So I have two questions:
1. Is it possible to show the results as columns (as in SQL view) instead of rows?
2. Is it possible to show all the records in one page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for GridView instead of DetailsView if you want to show the data as in a table-column-type view?

Comment: Thanks again it worked like a charm. However I still like to learn if that is possible with detailsview control.

Comment: As stated in documentation of DetailsView: ***"Displays the values of a single record from a data source in a table, where each data row represents a field of the record."*** the DetailsView is ment for different use than GridView. Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments by Esko, the details view only shows one record at a time. The details and Grid views are fast easy ways to display data, however if you wanted to customize how data is displayed, a more generic repeater would be the next logical choice, you would just have to do the formatting yourself.

Check out his article or google "asp.net repeater":

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804(v=vs.85).aspx

When I used to program in web forms a lot, I used repeaters even when a details or grid view would have done the job, because they are much more flexible and easier to maintain when someone asks for changes.

Cheers.

Comment: Getting good at repeaters is well worth the effort, in my opinion. The repeater can be used to make paged details views, grid views, or just about any other asp.net control for that matter once you become proficient with them.